# `OpenSearch.Client` - searching for documents with a field inside a set of values

Tags: c#, opensearch

I want to to find the documents that have a field match any of the values in a set, say an array of `new int[]{3,7,80}`.

I see that I could potentially do it like that:

```
var response = openSearchClient.Search<Document>(s => s
            .Index(documentsIndexName)
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(bq => bq
                    .Must(mq => mq.Term("fieldName", 3) || mq.Term("filedName", 7) || mq.Term("filedName", 8))
                )
            );
```

Maybe I could also build this query in a programmatic loop as well.

But isn't there a better way?

I see there is a `.TermSet()` method ([documentation here](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/term/terms-set/)), but it doesn't seem to produce the expected results for me:

```
var response = openSearchClient.Search<Document>(s => s
            .Index(documentsIndexName)
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(bq => bq
                    .Must(mq => TermsSet(f => f.Field(d => d.fieldName).Terms(new int[]{3,7,80})))
                )
            );
```

I have enabled logging of the queries and I see that the code above generates empty queries.

Can anyone tell me how this is done?

**Update:**

I think I should include a script for the `minimum_should_match` parameter. But I have tried this now, and it doesn't work:

```
mq.TermsSet(f => f.Field(d => d.fieldName).Terms(new int[]{3,7,80}).MinimumShouldMatchScript(sr => sr.Source("1")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use the `terms_set` query to find documents where a field matches any of the values in a set (an array in this case).

Try this :

```
var response = openSearchClient.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Index(documentsIndexName)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(bq => bq
            .Must(mq => mq
                .TermsSet(ts => ts
                    .Field(d => d.fieldName)
                    .Terms(new int[] { 3, 7, 80 })
                    .MinimumShouldMatchScript(sr => sr
                        .Source("1") // You can adjust the script based on your requirements
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I don't get any `MinimumShouldMatch()` method on `TermSetQueryDescriptor`, only a `MinimumShouldMatchField()` and a `MinimumShouldMatchScript()` (I use the latest Nuget package v. 1.5.0). The second should be what I need. I have tried using it as `.MinimumShouldMatchScript(sr => sr.Source("1")))`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. can you try this approach?

Comment: Yep. This works.